# NUnit- Custom Property Attribute display in Test Explorer window

Tags: visual-studio-2013, nunit, traits, system-testing

I created [custom property attribute](http://nunit.org/index.php?p=property&r=2.4) to link every system test to its driving requirements which is similar to something described in the link below:

[NUnit - Multiple properties of the same name? Linking to requirements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22187229/nunit-multiple-properties-of-the-same-name-linking-to-requirements/23533180#23533180)

I used the code given in the above link

> [Requirements(new string[] { "FR50082", "FR50084" })]
>
> [Test]
>
> public void TestSomething(string a, string b) { // blah, blah, blah
>
> Assert.AreNotEqual(a, b); }

which gets displayed in Test explorer (filter by traits) as :-

> Requirements[System.String[]] (1)
>
> ```
> TestSomething.....
> ```

But this is not what I was expecting. I require every requirement to get displayed individually though they are associated to the same test case in test explorer window.

I want to get it displayed as (in test explorer):-

> Requirements[FR50082] (1)
>
> ```
>    TestSomething.....
> ```
>
> Requirements[FR50084] (1)
>
> ```
>    TestSomething.....
> ```
>
> and so on....

So, if I am associating n number of Requirements to a test case, the test explorer should display the same test case n times under different requirements. Please let me know how could this be achieved ??

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like you are heading down the BDD (Behavior Driven Design) route. [SpecFlow](http://www.specflow.org/) is a good choice in .Net if you don't mind a VS extension.

The big win for you I think would be that you can reuse step definitions, what you're calling TestSomething. You can set up different contexts, your Requirements, as I'm reading them, and in the `Then` step call your TestSomething to verify all is well.